# There is a way to index information on different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySql schema looks like the following

```
create table TBL1 (id, person_id, ....otherData)
create table TBL2 (id, tbl1_id, month,year, ...otherData)
```

I am querying this schema as

```
select * from TBL1 join TBL2 on (TBL2.tbl1_id=TBL1.id)
where TBL1.person_id = ?
and TBL2.month=?
and TBL2.year=?
```

The current problem is that there is about 18K records on TBL1 associated with some person_id and there is also about 20K records on TBL2 associated with the same values of month/year.

For now i have two indexes.
index1 on TBL1(person_id) and other on index2 on TBL2(month,year)

when the database runs the query it uses index1 (ignoring month and year params) or index2 (ignoring person_id param). So, in both cases it scans about 20K records and doesn't perform as expected.

There is any way for me to create a single index on both tables or tell to mysql to merge de index on querying?

Comment: can you add your table definition here ? e.g show create table TBL1 ; and TBL2 also

Answer (score 0):

No, an index can belong to only one table.  You will need to look at the EXPLAIN for this query to see if you can determine where the performance issue is coming from.

Do you have indexes on `TBL2.tbl1_id` and `TBL1.id`?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Indexes are on single tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need compound indices on both table, to include the join column. If you add "ID" to both indices, the query optimizer should pick that up.

Can you post an "EXPLAIN"?